# Custom certificate validation in client and server with WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, x509certificate

I have a very specific configuration where WCF clients and servers needs to be authenticated using certificate.
Because this certificate will be only used by my clients and servers applications and is not possible to generate one dedicated certificate for each instance, then self-signed was the way.
So, I have the hole connection working well, I can attach the client certificate in the channel pointing to server, and the server service is also attaching its own certificate.
I want to be sure that only allowed clients can call my service, so validation must be done in server side.
I'm using a custom validator (X509CertificateValidator) overriding method Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
So far, all is ok, the method is called when connection established, it receive client's certificate with all properties and here is the question:

-How can I be sure the certificate I'm receiving is the original one in order to validate my client ??

Right now, I'm testing with a real(fake) certificate, exported from a website using HTTPS, (export the certificate showed in browser and installed locally).
I dont have the private key of course, but I'm able to attach this certificate in my client's connection and it is received well in server side.
All properties inside this certificate are the same than the original, but it is not !!
So, how can I validate that the certificate I'm receiving in server side is the original one and not just a copy ??
There is any way to put some signature in the call using the certificate's private key ??

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you override the validate function you are basically on your own. This is basically circumventing the whole certificate security system.
You need to make the certificate trusted on the server on the root level.
If you can't do that you have the following options:
1. use wild card cert (if all your servers can be on the same domain)
2. create your own certification authority

Comment: Well, i can't generate one certificate by machine, and even if I create my own certification authority the exported certificate will have it. I want to avoid clients use an exported certificate. How can I validate a client(s certificate to know it is a real one and not an exported ?? Thanks